# What is the significance or meaning of 筹 in 略胜一筹？

Tags: meaning

This text is talking about pearls.

另外，相比于淡水珍珠，海水珍珠多为有核珍珠，尺寸较大，表面更平滑，外观上更胜一筹。

更胜一筹，  略胜一筹：slightly better, a cut above.

Maybe, this comes from an ancient drinking [game](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E7%AD%B9):

壶矢。古代投壶用的签子，形如箭笴[arrow]

You got more arrows in the pot than your opponent, he had to drink more 白酒 as punishment.

The Chinese like drinking games! (Me too!)

baidu: 笴: 箭杆 gě, gǎn

Maybe 筹 was the classifier for 笴?? What is 筹 in 更胜一筹？

Comment: ？Simple Google will give you 筹 means 筹码

Answer (score 1):

筹 (chip) was a counting tool in ancient time. It was used by mathematicians for calculating.

運筹 was then used as a metaphor for the calculations strategists and military experts did

Idiom: "運筹帷幄" (moving chips inside the tent) means "strategizing in headquarters" ( before go the field or not even need to be in the field)

胜一筹 literally means "one step ahead" and it evolved to mean "one up"; "bested (v)" and  "a level above"

略胜一筹 (slightly better by one calculating step) means "slightly a step ahead" or "at a slightly higher level"

筹 is not a classifier but a noun for "level" in modern Chinese, e.g. "技高数**筹**" (a few **levels** higher in skill); "力胜一**筹**" (one **level** higher in strength)

> 更胜一筹， 略胜一筹：'slightly better', 'a cut above' are correct translations

Answer (score 0):

*Grand Ricci* defines 胜一筹 as:

> (loc.) L’emporter de justesse, de peu.

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=(loc.)%20L%E2%80%99emporter%20de%20justesse%2C%20de%20peu.) renders this into English as:

> To prevail narrowly, little.

---

一筹 is defined,

in *ABC* as:

> bit; notch; cut

and in *Pleco* as:

> chip (used as a counter)-move

and in *Oxford* as:

> brilliant move

and in *KEY* as:

> chip (used as a counter)/a move